# Why TreeMap put method doesn't work in Java?

Tags: java, treemap

I am trying to add some elements of 2 Lists in a TreeMap. I debugged the project and it seems that the put method for the TreeMap doesn't work, as it puts null for the Key and Value.

Here is the code:

```
package SubTest;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Matrice implements Cloneable,Comparable<Object> {

    private int nrCol;
    private int nrLin;
    private Object [][] matrix;

    public Matrice(){
        this.nrCol=0; this.nrLin=0;
        this.matrix=null;
    }
    public Matrice(int nrColoane, int nrLinii, Object[][]m){
        this.nrCol=nrColoane;
        this.nrLin=nrLinii;
        this.matrix=new Object[this.nrLin][this.nrCol];
        for(int i=0;i<this.nrLin;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<this.nrCol;j++)
                this.matrix[i][j]=m[i][j];
    }

    public int getnrCol(){
        return this.nrCol;
    }
    public void setnrCol(int c){
        this.nrCol=c;
    }
    public int getnrLin(){
        return this.nrLin;
    }
    public void setnrLin(int l){
        this.nrLin=l;
    }
    public Object[][] getMatrix(){
        return this.matrix;
    }

    public void citirefis(String fisier) throws FileNotFoundException, negativeNrLoc
    {
        BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fisier));
        List<PasagerVIP> vip=new ArrayList<PasagerVIP>();
        List<PasagerEc> ec=new ArrayList<PasagerEc>();
        String line=null; int nr=0;
        try{
            while((line = bf.readLine()) !=null){
                nr++;
                StringTokenizer token=new StringTokenizer(line," ");
                int n=0; String nume=null; String mycard=null; float nrloc=0; float varsta=0; int id=0;
                while(token.hasMoreElements()){
                    switch(n){
                    case 0: nume=token.nextToken(); break;
                    case 1: nrloc=Float.parseFloat(token.nextToken()); break;
                    case 2: varsta=Float.parseFloat(token.nextToken()); break;
                    case 3: id=Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()); break;
                    case 4: mycard=token.nextToken(); break;
                    }
                    n++;
                }
                if(mycard.contains("vip")) {
                    PasagerVIP v=new PasagerVIP(nume,nrloc,varsta,id,mycard);
                    vip.add(v);

                }
                else if(mycard.contains("ec")){
                    PasagerEc e=new PasagerEc(nume,nrloc,varsta,id,mycard);
                    ec.add(e);
                }
            }
            bf.close();
        }
        catch(IOException eoef){
            eoef.printStackTrace();}    

        Map<Float,Object> harta=new TreeMap<Float,Object>();
        int s1=vip.size(); 
        for(int i=0;i<s1;i++){

            harta.put(new Float(vip.get(i).getnrLoc()), vip.get(i));}
        int s2=ec.size();
        for(int i=0;i<s2;i++)
            harta.put(new Float(ec.get(i).getnrLoc()), ec.get(i));
        this.nrLin=(int)Math.sqrt(nr);
        this.nrCol=(int)Math.sqrt(nr);

        Set<Float> st=harta.keySet();
        Iterator<Float> it=st.iterator();
        for(int i=0;i<this.nrLin && it.hasNext();i++)
            for(int j=0;j<this.nrCol && it.hasNext();i++){
            Float loc=it.next();
            Object o=harta.get(loc);
            this.matrix[i][j]=o;}

        }
```

}

StackTrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SubTest.Matrice.citirefis(Matrice.java:128)
    at SubTest.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Comment: Any errors? please provide the full code.

Comment: What is the full error stacktrace?
IT should say on what line the NullPointerException occurs

Comment: It is impossible that both key and value are null, because a null value means `vip.get(i)` or `ec.get(i)` would be null, and you can't use null to call getnrLoc(). Please revise *carefully* what your lists contain and what is put into `harta`.

Comment: After I create my TreeMap I add each object in a matrix of Objects. The error is on this line: this.matrix[i][j]=o; as o is an null Object, because it isn't added to the TreeMap.

Comment: I have debbuged all my project and I am sure that vip.get(i) and ec.get(i) are not null.

Comment: Full code, full code, full code, full code,...

Comment: Are you trolling us? There's no line 128, max line no is 95.

Comment: It's 93. Sorry, I have deleted some of my other methods that weren't related.

Comment: Check the value of nr, nrLin and nrCol. A daring assumption that the square root should be exact.

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor should create the array properly, or there should be a method to create it in the required dimension, e.g.

```
public void createMatrix(){
    this.matrix = new Object[nrLin][nrCol];
}
```

and this should be called in line 86:

```
this.createMatrix();
```

The NPE results from `this.matrix` being null.